# How save log file in linux sever while sending logs to elk using syslog

Tags: docker, logging, docker-compose, microservices, elastic-stack

I using docker and elk stack for the logs. I have send log of my microservices using syslog in my logback.xml file. However, there are no log files in the server even though microservices created log files in my local computer when I run with Eclipes IDE. I also used docker-compose file to up Logstash, Elasticsearch and Kibana. The problem is when we need to down docker containers, there are no previous logs. Which is a big issue.

Here are problems

1 Is their a way to save log file in the server while sending logs to elk stack?

2 If not, Is their a way to permanently save log with elk-stack?

I have also added my docker-compose file for elk stack, logstash.config file and logback.xml of microservice.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
    elasticsearch:
        image: elasticsearch:6.5.0
        ports:
            - '9200:9200'
            - '9300:9300'
    kibana:
        image: kibana:6.5.0
        ports:
            - '5601:5601'
        depends_on:
            -  elasticsearch
    logstash:
        image: logstash:6.5.0
        ports:
            - '5000:5000'
        volumes:
            - $PWD/elk-config:/elk-config
        command: logstash -f /elk-config/logstash.config
        depends_on:
            -  elasticsearch
```

**logstash.config**

```
input {
    tcp {
    type => syslog
    port => 5000
    }
    udp {
    port => 5000
    type => syslog
    }
}
filter {
    if [type] == "syslog" {
        grok {
             match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\s+%{LOGLEVEL:severity}\s+\[%{DATA:service},%{DATA:trace},%{DATA:span},%{DATA:exportable}\]\s+%{DATA:pid}\s+---\s+\[%{DATA:thread}\]\s+%{DATA:class}\s+:\s+%{GREEDYDATA:rest}" }
        }  
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
    hosts => "elasticsearch"
    ssl => "false"
    index => "my-logs"
    document_type => "v1"
    }
}
```

**logback.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="5 seconds">
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml"/>
​
    <property scope="context" name="my-service" value="my-service"/>
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${BUILD_FOLDER:-logs}/${my-service}"/>​
    <property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN"
          value="%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} %clr(${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p}) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}"/>

<!-- Appender to log to console -->
    <appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <!-- Minimum logging level to be presented in the console logs-->
        <level>DEBUG</level>
    </filter>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        <charset>utf8</charset>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<!-- Appender to log to file -->​
<appender name="flatfile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        <charset>utf8</charset>
    </encoder>
</appender>
​
<!-- Appender to log to file in a JSON format -->
<appender name="logstash" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${LOG_FILE}.json</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.json.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
        <providers>
            <timestamp>
                <timeZone>UTC</timeZone>
            </timestamp>
            <pattern>
                <pattern>
                    {
                    "severity": "%level",
                    "service": "${springAppName:-}",
                    "trace": "%X{X-B3-TraceId:-}",
                    "span": "%X{X-B3-SpanId:-}",
                    "parent": "%X{X-B3-ParentSpanId:-}",
                    "exportable": "%X{X-Span-Export:-}",
                    "pid": "${PID:-}",
                    "thread": "%thread",
                    "class": "%logger{40}",
                    "rest": "%message"
                    }
                </pattern>
            </pattern>
        </providers>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="SYSLOG"
    class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SyslogAppender">
    <syslogHost>172.26.83.148</syslogHost>
    <port>5000</port>
    <facility>LOCAL1</facility>
    <suffixPattern>[%thread] %logger %msg</suffixPattern>
</appender>
​
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
    <appender-ref ref="logstash"/>
    <appender-ref ref="flatfile"/>
    <appender-ref ref="SYSLOG"/>
</root>
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be grateful.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Why is `<syslogHost>172.26.83.148</syslogHost>` hardcoded?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Thanks for the response I was followed a tutorial. Is there a better way. I am new to this stuff

Comment: Please add the link to the tutorial you have used to your question

Comment: @TarunLalwani I followed this tutorial. [Setting Up the ELK Stack With Spring Boot Microservices](https://dzone.com/articles/deploying-springboot-in-ecs-part-1)

Comment: Can you try with `<syslogHost>127.0.0.1</syslogHost>`

Comment: @TarunLalwani Logs are already in kibana dashboard. Issue is i can not find logs files in my linux sever

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194536/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-iuhettiarachchi).

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
volumes:
  - $PWD/elk-config:/elk-config
```

to

```
volumes:
  - $PWD/elk-config:/elk-config
  - $PWD/logs:/logspath/inside/container/
```

So that logs from inside the container actually get saved to your host machine as well. That is the way you will see files on the host machine

Answer (score 0):

The high level workflow for logging with containers is:

```
application stdout/stderr -> docker logging driver -> remote logging server
```

This follows the designed started by the [12 factor app principles](https://12factor.net/logs). The advantage of this design is the app can be moved from environment to environment without needing to be reconfigured. Instead the docker host itself is responsible for getting the logs to the remote server.

Logging drivers have many options. The default is a json logging driver which wraps the stdout in some json metadata to track details like when each line was written, and whether it was stdout or stderr. You can switch this logging driver to go to elastic via fluentd or gelf. However, I'm not a fan of changing the logging driver for two reasons. First, if the logging driver ever hangs, which can happen when your logging server has an outage, your apps may hang if they fill up their stdout buffer, turning a small logging outage into a large business outage. And second, without the json logging driver, `docker logs` will not work, removing the ability of local admins to assist in debugging issues.

Instead, my preference is to use some kind of logging forwarder. With Elastic, the common forwarder is Filebeat (if you were on Splunk, they have a universal forwarder of their own). You then leave docker logs using the json logging driver, allowing `docker logs` to work on existing containers. And Filebeat relays those container logs to the central Elastic server, giving you persistence when the containers are deleted.

For more details on running Filebeat, see the Elastic documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/running-on-docker.html